# Firefox save video from cache -- instead of redownloading

Tags: firefox, video, download, firefox-addon, browser-cache

Is there a way to save(download) videos already loaded on your browser after viewing them -- without re-downloading?

For example when it comes to pdfs, when you download and automatically view in the browser.. they are downloaded and saved in the Temp folder where you can go to and copy them to your Downloads folder or so.. without having to re-download it. (and thus wasting internet/server usage by downloading it for a second time)

When it comes to images if you click 'save image as'... it instantly saves it from cache, rather than re-downloading it. But when it comes to videos, when you "save video as" it re-downloads it from the beginning, rather than simply copy it from cache. Isn't it obvious that it should be saved from cache?

NOTE: I already know about a third party program called "VideoCacheView" which shows a list of videos/audios from every browser cache folders, but it almost never works, and it's not user friendly. (doesn't even show title or clean link) It works on facebook, but most of the time in my experience it doesn't work on most sites.

Ideally I'm looking for an add-on which adds a new option in the right click context menu called "save from cache" or so. Otherwise an add-on which opens a window, or a new tab, or a popup panel-box from the Toolbar.. which shows a list of videos saved in cache with their title and source url.

Edit: Or perhaps there are modifications one can make in about:config which would enable downloading from cache whenever it's available?